# How to get mobile data working (Three data SIM, Huawei ME906s, Xenial)

Tags: mobile-broadband, huawei, modem-manager

I've recently acquired a Thinkpad T460p that has a Huawei ME906s LTE modem card installed. I bought a PAYG SIM card from Three UK to use with it. I cannot get this combination to work. I'm using Ubuntu Mate 16.04.

The LTE modem works fine with the SIM card from my phone, and it also works fine with the SIM card from a 3G tablet, it just doesn't work with the particular SIM card I bought to use with it.

The Three SIM card works in the 3G tablet, and also in an old Acer netbook (running Ubuntu 14.04) that has an Option 3G modem card. It just doesn't work in the laptop I bought it for.

When I use mmcli to check the modem status I see a message saying "sim missing".

I've run modem-manager with the debug option turned on. The problem seems to be at the point at which mm checks to see whether it will have to prompt the user for the SIM PIN.

```
ModemManager[2821]: <debug> [1465982274.460019] [mm-broadband-modem.c:1290] modem_load_unlock_required(): checking if unlock required...
ModemManager[2821]: <debug> [1465982274.460049] [mm-port-serial.c:1237] mm_port_serial_open(): (ttyUSB0) device open count is 3 (open)
ModemManager[2821]: <debug> [1465982274.460086] [mm-port-serial.c:1294] _close_internal(): (ttyUSB0) device open count is 2 (close)
ModemManager[2821]: <debug> [1465982274.460121] [mm-port-serial-at.c:440] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): --> 'AT+CPIN?<CR>'
ModemManager[2821]: <debug> [1465982274.471229] [mm-port-serial-at.c:440] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): <-- '<CR><LF>+CME ERROR: 10<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[2821]: <debug> [1465982274.471373] [mm-serial-parsers.c:364] mm_serial_parser_v1_parse(): Got failure code 10: SIM not inserted
ModemManager[2821]: <debug> [1465982274.471425] [mm-iface-modem.c:266] load_unlock_required_ready(): Couldn't check if unlock required: 'SIM not inserted'
```

(these lines are output while modem-manager initializes with debug turned on, I haven't run any further commands to try to use the modem)

When I generate the same debug output but using my phone SIM, which IS recognized, I get:

```
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.133951] [mm-broadband-modem.c:1290] modem_load_unlock_required(): checking if unlock required...
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.133981] [mm-port-serial.c:1237] mm_port_serial_open(): (ttyUSB0) device open count is 3 (open)
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.134018] [mm-port-serial.c:1294] _close_internal(): (ttyUSB0) device open count is 2 (close)
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.134058] [mm-port-serial-at.c:440] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): --> 'AT+CPIN?<CR>'
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.145234] [mm-port-serial-at.c:440] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): <-- '<CR><LF>+CPIN: READY<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.145370] [mm-port-serial.c:1294] _close_internal(): (ttyUSB0) device open count is 1 (close)
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.145422] [huawei/mm-broadband-modem-huawei.c:676] load_unlock_retries(): loading unlock retries (huawei)...
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.145475] [mm-port-serial.c:1237] mm_port_serial_open(): (ttyUSB0) device open count is 2 (open)
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.145523] [mm-port-serial-at.c:440] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): --> 'AT^CPIN?<CR>'
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.156692] [mm-port-serial-at.c:440] debug_log(): (ttyUSB0): <-- '<CR><LF>^CPIN: READY,,10,3,10,3<CR><LF><CR><LF>OK<CR><LF>'
ModemManager[2591]: <debug> [1465986560.157040] [mm-iface-modem.c:3062] update_lock_info_context_step(): SIM is ready, running after SIM unlock step...
```

It seems to me that this shows that in the low-level communication between the modem and the SIM card that takes place during the AT+CPIN? command the card is generating some response that the driver for the Huawei card does not expect, but only when using the card from Three. I don't know how to eavesdrop on those communications to see what's actually happening.

Note that the Option modem card in my old netbook handles this dialog quite happily, so the problem is present in the Huawei modem driver in Xenial but not in the Option modem driver in Trusty.

Is there anything else I can do here, or do I have to wait for an updated driver?

Comment: A workaround may be to disable the PIN code request for the SIM, if that's feasible. I don't know what could be causing this problem though.

Comment: PIN code IS disabled for the SIM card in question. That doesn't stop modem-manager trying to find out whether it is enabled or not and so issuing the problematic command. I shall try ENabling the PIN, and see what change that makes. Note, however, that the SIM from my phone has PIN enabled while that from my tablet does not, and they both work in the Thinkpad.

Comment: Okay, I somehow missed that. If you want, I can start a [bounty](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on your question to give it more visibility and a better chance of getting an answer. (I can only do that in two days though)

Comment: I put the Three SIM in my phone and enabled PIN verification, but the card is still not recognized in the Thinkpad. It was worth a try! Is there any (software) way to view/debug the exchange of data between the modem and the SIM? I guess it would have to depend on debug features in the driver ...?

Comment: I have no idea unfortunately, sorry.